# Make my submit event wait for verification

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a bit of code like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        bootbox.prompt("Please enter the summary value for the entries you made.", function(result) {
            var enteredSummary = parseFloat(result);
            ... more stuff...
```

As my prompt dialog pops up, it posts the form before waiting for my UI response.  How do I force it to behave synchronously?  I don't want anything posted until the user has clicked the button and the value they enter matches the data they put on the screen.

Comment: Use a `confirm()`. Or start by preventing the form from submitting and submit it manually in the callback after your validation.

Comment: `confirm()` doesn't let them summarize the values they entered.  I need to evaluate an input before allowing the form to submit.

Comment: change return to return false